# Mouse buttons 6 and 7 send two events per physical press in Ubuntu under Hyper-V

Tags: 18.04, mouse, hyper-v

I have an Ubuntu 18.0.4.5 VM running under Hyper-V.  I have a mouse with the normal two buttons, a scroll wheel, and two side buttons that map to buttons 6 and 7.  All of the mouse functionality works fine except for the two side buttons. The side buttons produce press and release events when physically depressed, and again when released.  I have these buttons mapped via xbindkeys to produce Alt+L and Alt+R keypresses for navigation, so I get two navigation events per button press which is problematic. When I run `xinput test 6` (where 6 is the ID of the xrdp mouse), I very clearly get a press event and a release event when I press either of the side buttons, then another pair of press and release events when I release the button.  Here's what it looks like when I run xinput test and press each of the buttons exactly once in turn:

```
~$ xinput test 6
button press   1 
button release 1 
button press   2 
button release 2 
button press   3 
button release 3 
button press   4 
button release 4 
button press   5 
button release 5 
button press   7 
button release 7 
button press   7 
button release 7 
button press   6 
button release 6 
button press   6 
button release 6
```

And here's the output from xinput:

```
~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xrdpMouse                                 id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xrdpKeyboard                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I have tested this with three different mice to rule out mechanical issues (and the mice all work normally in the Windows host OS without this sort of button doubling).  I see the same behavior using xev.

What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

I did fumble around for a bit attempting to get the buttons mapped to the keys that I wanted, so it's possible I messed something up, but I don't believe I touched anything that could have caused this.

In response to a comment, here's the output of `xinput list-props 6` :

```
~$ xinput list-props 6
Device 'xrdpMouse':
    Device Enabled (113):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (115): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (229): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (230):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (231):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (232):    12.500000
```

Comment: I don't know if it's possible but check if you have more than one xbindkeys processes active? `ps -ef |grep xbindkeys | grep -v grep` should only be a single line output.

Comment: I only get one line of output, and given that xinput shows two press/release cycles for each physical button press I'm pretty sure that the problem is not with xbindkeys

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I mis-read/mis-understood your first post slightly. Can you post the results of `xinput list-props 6`

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?  I'm having the exact same problem on 20.04 and 18.04, even not using Hyper-V

Comment: No, I never figured this out and kinda just gave up since I haven't been using the VM lately anyway.  Sorry :(